# Why does this function returns the last argument when called right after definition

Tags: javascript

```
function foo(x) {
  return x;
}
foo(1); // returns 1 as expected

function bar(x) {
  return x;
}(1,2,3); // returns 3
```

I couldn't understand why does `bar` function returns the last argument.
Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Your second example your not even calling bar,.  It's just the same as doing `(1,2,3)`, and what you seeing is just how the console is showing it. In fact its even the same as doing `1,2,3`.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? What's the expected behaviour?

Comment: You are right @Keith I overlooked that, I saw it in a quiz and I thought it's a kind of IIFE I haven't seen.
@NicoHaase Well, I only tested this on dev-tools console, and seeing `3` after `}(1,2,3);` tricked me. I could have probably see the grouping if I just log the parameter :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `bar()` function is being interpreted as a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) and not as a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), as a result, the `(1, 2, 3)` is not the call syntax for functions `()`, but rather the [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) using the [comma-operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), which returns the last value of 3 (which is then logged in the console). If it's on separate lines it may become clearer:

```
function bar(x) { // declares a function bar
  console.log("running"); // never logged
  return x;
}
// Uses the grouping operator `( )`, with the comma operator
(1,2,3); // returns 3
```

If you make `bar()` a function expression, then it will behave as expected (here I'm using the unary plus `+` to achieve that):

```js
+function bar(x) {
  console.log("running"); // logged
  return x;
}(1,2,3); // returns 1
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you :) I saw this code in a javascript quiz and always interpreted it as a function expression. Turns out it was just a small trick :) Thank you for your detailed explanation.

Comment: @fatihsolhan Just for your information, This function can be turned into self invoking anonymous function in which case this calls itself. 

`(function (x) {
  console.log("running"); // logged
  return x; 
}(1,2,3)); // returns 1`

Comment: @fatihsolhan no worries - I also recommend checking out [this](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/0a8a3440a96a1f9ca2fdba71c662) AST explorer (made by [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling)), it can help with things like this